# Libgit2sharp Push Performance Degrading With Many Commits

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

The project I am working on uses GIT in a weird way. Essentially it writes and pushes one commit at a time. The project could result in one branch having hundreds of thousands of commits. When testing we found that after only about 500 commits the performance of the GIT push started to degrade. Upon further investigation using a process monitor we believe that the degradation is due to a walk of the entire tree for the branch being pushed. Since we are only ever pushing one new commit at any given time is there any way to optimize this?

Alternatively is there a way to limit the commit history to be something like 50 commits to reduce this overhead?

I am using LibGit2Sharp Version 0.20.1.0

**Update 1**

To test I wrote the following code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    string remotePath = @"E:\GIT Test\Remote";
    string localPath = @"E:\GIT Test\Local";
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, "TestFile.txt");

    Repository.Init(remotePath, true);
    Repository.Clone(remotePath, localPath);

    Repository repo = new Repository(localPath);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(localFilePath, RandomString((i % 2 + 1) * 10));
        repo.Stage(localFilePath);

        Commit commit = repo.Commit(
            string.Format("Commit number: {0}", i), 
            new Signature("TestAuthor", "TestEmail@Test.com", System.DateTimeOffset.Now),
            new Signature("TestAuthor", "TestEmail@Test.com", System.DateTimeOffset.Now));      

        Stopwatch pushWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Remote defaultRemote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
        repo.Network.Push(defaultRemote, "refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master");
        pushWatch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Push {0} took {1}ms", i, pushWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }
}

private const string Characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

/// <summary>
/// Get a Random string of the specified length
/// </summary>
public static string RandomString(int size)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = Characters[Random.Next(Characters.Length)];
    }

    return new string(buffer);
}
```

And ran the process monitor found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

The time for each push ended up being generally low with large spikes in time increasing both in frequency and in latency. When looking at the output from the process monitor I believe these spikes lined up with a long stretch where objects in the .git\objects folder were being accessed. For some reason occasionally on a pull there are large reads of the objects which when looked at closer appears to be a walk through the commits and objects.

The above flow is a condensed version of the actual flow we were actually doing in the project. In our actual flow we would first create a new branch "Temp" from "Master", make a commit to "Temp", push "Temp", merge "Temp" with "Master" then push "Master". When we timed each part of that flow we found the push was by far the longest running operation and it was increasing in elapsed time as the commits piled up on "Master".

**Update 2**
I recently updated to use libgit2sharp version 0.20.1.0 and this problem still exists. Does anyone know why this occurs?

**Update 3**
We change some of our code to create the temporary branch off of the first commit ever on the "Master" branch to reduce the commit tree traversal overhead but found it still exists. Below is an example that should be easy to compile and run. It shows the tree traversal happens when you create a new branch regardless of the commit position. To see the tree traversal I used the process monitor tool above and command line GIT Bash to examine what each object it opened was. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it expected behavior or am I just doing something wrong? It appears to be the push that causes the issue.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string remotePath = @"E:\GIT Test\Remote";
    string localPath = @"E:\GIT Test\Local";
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, "TestFile.txt");

    Repository.Init(remotePath, true);
    Repository.Clone(remotePath, localPath);

    // Setup Initial Commit
    string newBranch;
    using (Repository repo = new Repository(localPath))
    {
        CommitRandomFile(repo, 0, localFilePath, "master");
        newBranch = CreateNewBranch(repo, "master");
        repo.Checkout(newBranch);
    }

    // Commit 1000 times to the new branch
    for(int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        using(Repository repo = new Repository(localPath))
        {
            CommitRandomFile(repo, i, localFilePath, newBranch);
        }
    }

    // Create a single new branch from the first commit ever
    // For some reason seems to walk the entire commit tree
    using(Repository repo = new Repository(localPath))
    {               
        CreateNewBranch(repo, "master");
    }
}

private const string Characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

/// <summary>
/// Generate and commit a random file to the specified branch
/// </summary>
public static void CommitRandomFile(Repository repo, int seed, string rootPath, string branch)
{
    File.WriteAllText(rootPath, RandomString((seed % 2 + 1) * 10));
    repo.Stage(rootPath);

    Commit commit = repo.Commit(
        string.Format("Commit: {0}", seed), 
        new Signature("TestAuthor", "TestEmail@Test.com", System.DateTimeOffset.Now),
        new Signature("TestAuthor", "TestEmail@Test.com", System.DateTimeOffset.Now));      

    Stopwatch pushWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    repo.Network.Push(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], "refs/heads/" + branch + ":refs/heads/" + branch);
    pushWatch.Stop();

    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Push {0} took {1}ms", seed, pushWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a new branch from the specified source
/// </summary>
public static string CreateNewBranch(Repository repo, string sourceBranch)
{
    Branch source = repo.Branches[sourceBranch];
    string newBranch = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    repo.Branches.Add(newBranch, source.Tip);

    Stopwatch pushNewBranchWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    repo.Network.Push(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], "refs/heads/" + newBranch + ":refs/heads/" + newBranch);
    pushNewBranchWatch.Stop();

    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Push of new branch {0} took {1}ms", newBranch, pushNewBranchWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    return newBranch;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get a Random string of the specified length
/// </summary>
public static string RandomString(int size)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = Characters[Random.Next(Characters.Length)];
    }

    return new string(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Which is this "entire tree" that's being walked? If you're pushing one commit which is a descendant of what's in the remote, the commit walk will be of one commit and would only depend on the differences between each tip. How have you determined that tree walking is causing the slowdown?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of libgit2sharp you're using. The behaviour you're describing would make sense with an old version.

Comment: When I posted I was using libgit2sharp version 0.20.0.0

Comment: In your code samples, you keep using a local path. Does this effect also happen when pushing via `git://` or `https://`? The local path code doesn't necessarily try to be quick.

Comment: We are using a local DFS to host the remote so all I have is a path to a network share when I push/pull (example: \\prod\git\storage). Is there a way to configure it to be faster even when using just a simple network share as the remote?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior pushing against a locally hosted repo? Can you reproduce this behavior when pushing over https (against a GitHub hosted repo for instance)?

Comment: I observed similar behavior.  Here is some performance testing result.
For each test run, I had created an empty repository in a folder containing the files.

Test Runs:
1) 2707 untracked files – single commit-  added, committed, and pushed ~13 mins
2) 2707 untracked files using 100 per interval – added, committed, and pushed 11.87 mins
3) 2707 untracked files using 500 per interval – added, committed, and pushed 11.68 mins
4) 2707 untracked files using 20 per interval – added, committed, and pushed 6.80 mins

Smaller number of files per commit and push made a significant difference.